# function to describe a graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have a graph that looks like this.

[image: picture]

I would like to know how to define this as a function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot infer/deduce an exact single formula
(analytical representation) just from a graph like the one
you have.

Instead you can discretize the points on the X axis,
and then use some polynomial, or (better) a set of polynomials
i.e. a spline to approximate it your function.
The more points you pick on the X axis, the better the approximation would be.

See also:

[Splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics))

Comment: Thank you. Splines is exactly what I was looking for.